# GridView.getChildAt returns null when testing with Robolectric

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, robolectric

I am trying to test a GridView to ensure that it is loading images with Robolectric. `GridView.getChildAt(0)` returns null even though there is data in the adapter. I understand that this is because `getChildAt()` returns based on what is shown on screen.

Is there a way to get this test working in Robolectric or do I have to move to testing on device (eg. with Espresso)?

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "../../src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18, reportSdk = 18)
public class ImageGridFragmentTest {

    private ImageGridFragment mImageGridFragment;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
        mImageGridFragment = new ImageGridFragment();
        startFragment(mImageGridFragment);
    }

    @Test
    public void testImageGridFragmentLoaded() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mImageGridFragment);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadImageToGrid() throws Exception {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) mImageGridFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.gv_image_grid);
        Log.d("gridView.size", Integer.toString(gridView.getCount()));

        assertEquals(0, gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        View itemView = (View) gridView.getChildAt(0);
        assertNotNull(itemView); // Test fails here

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_loaded_image);
        ShadowDrawable shadowDrawable = Robolectric.shadowOf(imageView.getDrawable());
        assertEquals(R.drawable.sample_image, shadowDrawable.getCreatedFromResId());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the gridView.size or is the adapter null? Possbily `assertNotNull(gridView.getAdapter());`

Comment: The gridView.size returned by the Log.d is 2. I add two items to the adapter. The adapter doesn't seem to be null (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as thoroughly testing the system but might be the best that can be done.

```
@Test
public void shouldLoadImageToGrid() throws Exception {
    GridView gridView = (GridView) mImageGridFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.gv_image_grid);

    ImageGridData data = (ImageGridData) gridView.getAdapter().getItem(0);
    assertEquals((long)R.drawable.sample_image, (long)data.getImageId());
}
```